# SQL columns that were Inner joined showing up separately?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to join some tables together, but when I join them the columns I am joining on are showing up separately.

My code looks something like this:

```
    Select * FROM

    SimulationOutput as SO 

    Inner Join SimulationInput as SI
    ON  SO.Key = SI.Key 
    AND
    SO.Scenario = SI.Scenario
```

When I do this, I get the result I expected but my result also includes duplicates of The "Key" columns and the "Scenario" columns that I just joined on.

Is this expected behavior?

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_inner

On that website

I ran the following code:

```
Select * FROM
Orders

Inner Join Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID

ORDER BY Orders.CustomerID
```

And in that output, the CustomerId column only shows up once, the Customers.CustomerID was dropped. I am trying to understand why this is happening in the latter, but not the former.

The reason I ask is because I intend to use a series of nested tables. And I'm running into duplicate column problems where SQL doesn't know which Scenario column to choose. I understand that I can specify the specific column, but I was planning on specifying my specific columns at the top fo the nested loop, and use a series of nested Select* in between.

So the structure would be something like

```
Select Column1, Column2, Column3 From
(Select * FROM ...... 
   (Select * FROM.......
      (Select * FROM..... ) as T1) as T2) as T3
```

I understand that this may not be ideal and for this question my end result is moot, I want to understand why the columns I'm joining on aren't being dropped the way they are on the w3schools website.

Is it because I am using an AND statement? Is there a better way to inner join using multiple criteria? Is it because of my version of SQL (TSQL?)

Image From W3 schools output

[image]

Comment: Which database engine are you using? This is the expected behavior of MS SQL Server, I know there are other database engines out there that provide what you are looking for though with things like "natural join".

Comment: If you execute `SELECT * ...` on that w3schools simulator you'll also get the customer ID from both tables. (Note that the predefined query there is `SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName ...` you have to change it to use `*`.) And yes, that is expected behavior, as `*` means "all columns".

Comment: DavidP I believe I am using Microsoft SQL Server. So I think that might answer my question. Is there a way to modify the code to drop the duplicated column that was joined on? This is really aggravating

Comment: @stickybit I just ran it again on W3schools and it only showed me 1 CustomerID column. I uploaded a picture of it, is there some nuance to the code that I accidentally entered there without realizing that's causing the column to be dropped

Comment: It is not because of the AND statement. It doesn't affect it at all. I think, listing the specific columns is the only thing you can do.

Comment: @JedBartlet: I get `Orders.CustomerID` and `Customers.CustomerID`. Strange that this is missing in your result. But anyway, the right behavior og the DBMS is to include all columns from all inner joined tables selected from when using `*`. Maybe that w3schools have some extra in their simulator, that excludes some columns. But that's not real world DBMS behavior.

Comment: Looks like it can be browser dependant, which is unexpected! Select * in Chrome shows one CustomerID column, IE shows two. There's definitely some post-processing going on, it's nothing to do with your SQL query. `SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.CustomerID, Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CustomerName
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID;` in Chrome also shows only one CustomerID column :)

Comment: Oh wow, ok hmmm. So in general there's no way to actually tell SQL to do that? Some kind of Select* except (joined columns) or something? I can specify the columns I need, but it's much much much shorter to specify the ones I don't need.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Note using Select * is generally regarded as bad practice outside of quick ad hoc queries.

Comment: @GarethLyons, gotcha. I don't think I'm exactly using SQL the way it's meant to be, I'm doing calculations and then I need to store those calculations and then do calculations on those calculations etc. Probably just best to do the latter half in another language where I can more easily create variables.